# Why is console output from a ctypes library coming after output of the Python code that executes it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I need to use functions defined in a *.so dynamic library file in my Python code.

After compiling the library and running below Python code:

```
from ctypes import *

so_file = "./libtest.so.0"
log = CDLL(so_file)
ret = log.hello_world(5)
print("print from python", ret)
```

the output is:

```
print from python 5
Hello world for 5 times
```

In `ret = log.hello_world(5)`, the function is printing `"Hello world for %d times"`.

As you can see my printing output is in reverse.

Why does this happen and what is the solution to resolving this problem?

Comment: Just a guess, you need to flush stdout?

Comment: in Python sometimes function `print()` is buffering data and it sends on screen only if there is `\n`  at the end. And when there is no `\n` then it may need to run `sys.stdout.flush()`. Maybe C code needs something similar